# Using signal.h to terminate a process running in background when the process is executed again

Tags: c, linux, signals

Assuming this program is running in background.

Assuming headers are included e.g signal.h...

```
void SignalHandler(int sig);
int fd;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


signal(SIGINT,SignalHandler);
signal(SIGHUP,SignalHandler);
signal(SIGTERM,SignalHandler);

setsid();
close(0);
close(1);
close(2);


fd = open("/myPIPE", O_RDWR);
if(fd<0){
perror("open() error");
exit(1);
}

while (1) {
        err = read(fd, strbuf, 256);
        if(err)
            syslog(LOG_INFO,"%s",strbuf);   

        }
close(fd);

}

void SignalHandler(int sig){

if(fd!=-1)
close(fd);
exit(0);

}
```

Assuming that this code is already running. and has program name of testsignal. When i run it again in the terminal ./testsignal & the process just keeps on adding up.. the currently running process should exit and the new process should replace the old one. so only process should be running. I need help on this. Thanks

Comment: Please post your actual code. there is no fd in scope of signalhandler.

Comment: My bad there you go.. the fd variable is global..

Comment: you need to store old pid somewhere, or find pid in procfs

Comment: will openlog("testpipe", LOG_PID) do?

Comment: How will the new process know which is the PID of the old process? You could pass it as an argument to the program (no argument, no old process to kill).  You could store it in a well known location.  (It's slightly worrying that you can create `/myPIPE`; you should not normally create files in the root directory of the system.)  Your signal handler isn't really necessary; the system will close the open file descriptor anyway — but I recognize that it's there for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: No, `openlog("testpipe", LOG_PID)` won't do; the `openlog()` function takes three arguments, at least according to the [manual](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/openlog/) [pages](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_openlog.htm) I found.  Also, the new process would have to arrange to open the log file, read to the end, find the last message, analyze the PID from that, close the log, and then send a signal to that process, before opening the log for itself, and writing a message so that its successor can find it.

Comment: Well this is just sample code just to test how to handle signals.. can you show an example how can i do that?.. I got this idea from remserial.. but why don't this work on my part? in remserial it didn't store the pid in any file why is it working?

Comment: Notice that `read` returns the number of read bytes, or -1 on error. So the line `err = read(fd, strbuf, 256);`is misleading. It should be `nbr = read(fd,strbuf,256);` and you handle the case when `nbr<0` using `errno` (which could be `EINTR` in particular) -or `nbr==0`on EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a simplification of yours in that it doesn't use `syslog()`.  It also doesn't close standard input, standard output and standard error, so the daemon still has a way to log information to standard output (specifically).  This makes it easier for me to test.

The `flprintf()` function is used to ensure that all outputs to standard output are flushed; it reduces the number of boring 4-line blocks of code in the program.  The program also logs more of its activity, which also makes it easier to see what's going on.  (In part that's because I managed to overlook the commented-out `close()` system calls.)  I make everything that doesn't have to be visible outside of this source file static; that means only `main()` is not static.  This code also ensures that the string read is null terminated, so long strings followed by short ones don't produce messages that are a mish-mash of the short one plus the remains of the longer ones.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

static void flprintf(const char *fmt, ...);
static void SignalHandler(int sig);
static int fd = -1;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int nbytes;
    char strbuf[257];

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        int pid = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (kill(pid, SIGINT) != 0)
            flprintf("Failed to deliver SIGINT to PID %d\n", pid);
        else
            flprintf("SIGINT successfully delivered to PID %d\n", pid);
    }

    flprintf("Starting - %d\n", (int)getpid());

    signal(SIGINT, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGHUP, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGTERM, SignalHandler);

    setsid();
    //close(0);
    //close(1);
    //close(2);

    fd = open("./myPIPE", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("open() error");
        exit(1);
    }

    flprintf("Starting read loop\n");

    while ((nbytes = read(fd, strbuf, sizeof(strbuf)-1)) > 0)
    {
        strbuf[nbytes] = '\0';
        flprintf("<<%s>>\n", strbuf);
    }

    flprintf("Read EOF - %d exiting\n", (int)getpid());

    close(fd);
    return(0);
}

void SignalHandler(int sig)
{
    flprintf("Received signal %d - %d exiting\n", sig, (int)getpid());
    if (fd != -1)
        close(fd);
    exit(0);
}

static void flprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

I tested on Mac OS X 10.7.5 (GCC 4.7.1, not that it matters much in this case).  The only behaviour I found surprising once it was working was that the program didn't get EOF when the process writing a message to the FIFO closed.  However, I think that's explained by the `O_RDWR` on the `open()` call; there's still a process (this one) with the FIFO open.  Recompile with `O_RDONLY` and the process exits after the first time something writes to the pipe...sanity rules.  What you've done is fine as a way of achieving a FIFO that never reports EOF.  (It also explains why the process didn't block on the open, waiting for a process to open the FIFO.)

Sample output:

```
$ ./sig >> sig.out &
[1] 47598
$ cat sig.out
Starting - 47598
Starting read loop
$ echo "Testing, 1, 2, 3" > myPIPE
$ cat sig.out
Starting - 47598
Starting read loop
<<Testing, 1, 2, 3
>>
$ echo "Another test - 1, 2, 3" > myPIPE
$ echo "Mini test - 1, 2" > myPIPE
$ cat sig.out
Starting - 47598
Starting read loop
<<Testing, 1, 2, 3
>>
<<Another test - 1, 2, 3
>>
<<Mini test - 1, 2
>>
$ ./sig 47598 >> sig.out &
[2] 47610
$ cat sig.out
Starting - 47598
Starting read loop
<<Testing, 1, 2, 3
>>
<<Another test - 1, 2, 3
>>
<<Mini test - 1, 2
>>
Received signal 2 - 47598 exiting
SIGINT successfully delivered to PID 47598
Starting - 47610
Starting read loop
[1]-  Done                    ./sig >> sig.out
$ echo "Testing, 1, 2, 3" > myPIPE
$ cat sig.out
Starting - 47598
Starting read loop
<<Testing, 1, 2, 3
>>
<<Another test - 1, 2, 3
>>
<<Mini test - 1, 2
>>
Received signal 2 - 47598 exiting
SIGINT successfully delivered to PID 47598
Starting - 47610
Starting read loop
<<Testing, 1, 2, 3
>>
$ kill 47610
$ cat sig.out
Starting - 47598
Starting read loop
<<Testing, 1, 2, 3
>>
<<Another test - 1, 2, 3
>>
<<Mini test - 1, 2
>>
Received signal 2 - 47598 exiting
SIGINT successfully delivered to PID 47598
Starting - 47610
Starting read loop
<<Testing, 1, 2, 3
>>
Received signal 15 - 47610 exiting
[2]+  Done                    ./sig 47598 >> sig.out
$
```

Comment: Thanks... Great answer very detailed.. I'll just like to make changes so when it stores the pid to a pidfile so i don't type in as an argument. Can i put the pid in a file like pidfile e.g /tmp/sig.pid so when the program starts it first checks the file and kill it then start it again so it don't create a second instance of the program. thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way.  Some things to watch for are (1) whether you'll run into conflicts with your fixed name, or (2) whether someone could remove your pid file and then create a new one that points to  a system process that they want killed.  This sort of thing would be a problem if your program is run by root.  But it probably doesn't matter for a coursework exercise.

Comment: hmmm so creating a pidfile is not advisable.. Thank you so much you've been a great help. I have another question.. is setsid() without forking good?

Comment: The signal handler calls non-async-signal-safe functions.  `vprintf`, for example, might interrupt itself during memory allocation under the hood.  Messy.

Comment: @pilcrow: Yeah — strictly you're correct.  This is demonstration code; I chose not to inundate the OP with those details. His original code was much nearer to clean from that viewpoint.